# VMware ESXi - blue screen - no file configured to dump data

Tags: vmware-esxi

I have a VMware ESXi 6.0.0 running on a Dell server. It is up and running to about 1 year without any problem. Today, it show a blue screen, and all VMs are down suddenly. (please check the image below.)

According to the error screen, is it related to diskDumpSlotSize?

Thank you!!

[blue screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFNU3.png)

Answer (score 1):

It's a page-fault, I'm not sure if there's a way to tell from that whether it's a hardware or software fault - you'd need to get your coredump analysed by VMware to be sure sorry.